# Where is memory allocated when creating object on stack?

Tags: c++, oop, object

I dont understand what is happening in the memory in this scenario:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Ninja n; //create a object on the stack?
    Ninja * n = new Ninja;  //create a pointer the the object on the heap?

    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Yes, first one on stack, second one in heap

Comment: Variables and objects that are known in advance are put on the stack. Variables and objects that are created dynamically during execution is put on the heap.

Comment: so this is in fact the run-time(creating a object on heap during execution), and compile time in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one,

```
Ninja n1;
```

is created on the stack. At then end of the scope (the main function in this case), the object goes out of scope and the allocated memory for this Ninja is cleared.

The second one,

```
Ninja * n2 = new Ninja;
```

is created on the heap. This memory is not cleared as the end of the scope, the object still exists after the function is finishes.